# Compiling R from source: RStudio doesn't find the libraries if started directly

Tags: r, rstudio, intel-mkl

I have compiled R 4.1.0 from source against the Intel MKL.

I have put:

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/env/vars.sh intel64
```

in `~/.bashrc`.

If I open a `.R` file with RStudio, no problem.

But if I open RStudio directly, it is unable to start R correctly, giving me the error:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_gf_lp64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why is that? Doesn't RStudio run `~/.bashrc` when started directly?

I am running Fedora 34 Workstation.

Comment: When you say "If I open a .R file with RStudio, no problem." -- how exactly are you doing that? Are you using the command line or some GUI? Programs don't usually run your `.bashrc` file automatically because they don't usually start a new shell. Your environment is just inherited from your current shell.

Comment: Depending on what type of system you are on, you could simply fix this via a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local-mkl.conf` with entry of you MKL library directory.  Otherwise, you could for example use the script I releases [four+ years ago in this GH repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb) to update MKL as system libraries (via .deb files, easy to uninstall cleanly). In short, this has nothing to do with R but only with how your system does (or, rather, does not) tell its dynamc linker where these libraries are.

Comment: @MrFlick When I say "If I open a .R file with RStudio, no problem", I mean I double click on the .R file in nautilus (the file manager), which is configured to open it using RStudio

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am on Fedora 34 Workstation. So I am .rpm based. But why opening an `.R` file doesn't raise the issue, and just opening RStudio from scratch raises the issue?

Comment: My first tip of using `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` to add a local file should work perfectly for you.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It did. It did work after I also called `sudo ldconfig` after creating the `.conf` file. But why opening a `.R` file directly doesn't give the problem?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel If you make it into an answer I will accept it

Comment: Thanks, very kind -- and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When shared libraries are stored in "non-standard locations" we have to tell the dynamic linker about it.  That is sometimes done in the calling script (often the case with bundled software, e.g. when you download RStudio which ships with a fair number of local builds of shared libraries) but a more general solution is to tell `ldconfig` via its configuration.

Older systems used a line per directory in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.  Newer systems generalize this (like many other configurations) with a directory containing small files with entries.  So you can create a file named, say, `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local-mkl.conf`, and place the directory path in there. If you then run `sudo ldconfig` all applications will know about it -- including R and RStudio calling R.